# Load graph from json using JointJS

Tags: json, graph

I'm having a problem trying to load a graph form json using JointJS. I know the theory (https://resources.jointjs.com/tutorial/serialization), however, I still do not know how to show a graph.

This is my html file:

```
    <!-- JointJS libraries omitted for space -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">            
            function read_json() {
                $.getJSON("/jointsjdemo/demo.json", function(data) {
                    var graph = new joint.dia.Graph;        
                    graph.fromJSON(data);

                    var paper = new joint.dia.Paper({
                        el: document.getElementById('myholder'),
                        model: graph,
                        width: 600,
                        height: 100,
                        gridSize: 1
                    });
                });
            }
            read_json();
        </script>
```

And this is my json file:

```
{"cells":[{"type":"standard.Rectangle","position":{"x":100,"y":30},"size":{"width":100,"height":40},"angle":0,"id":"42a7f123-1f0d-4d06-b49e-8cbcbbb17e23","z":1,"attrs":{"body":{"fill":"blue"},"label":{"fill":"white","text":"Hello"}}},{"type":"standard.Rectangle","position":{"x":400,"y":30},"size":{"width":100,"height":40},"angle":0,"id":"6ecac186-b9c1-4755-97db-704cd9b9156f","z":1,"attrs":{"body":{"fill":"blue"},"label":{"fill":"white","text":"World!"}}},{"type":"standard.Link","source":{"id":"42a7f123-1f0d-4d06-b49e-8cbcbbb17e23"},"target":{"id":"6ecac186-b9c1-4755-97db-704cd9b9156f"},"id":"fa23e165-3c9f-46f8-9fe9-e6660d4086ca","z":2,"attrs":{}}]}
```

When a load the web page, it shows nothing on screen. I'm deployed my app in Apache Tomcat. Using Chrome Developer Tools, no errors are shown in Console.

I dont know what I'm missing.

Any help please? The json file was generated through toJSON command.

P.D. I think it should be better to hire someone, but I'm still trying to do this.

Comment: The json file is reading well... I read the file using this `console.log( "JSON Data: " + data.cells[ 0 ].type );` and it printed: `Rectangle`. But not showed the graph in the web page.

Comment: Oh... I did it. The problem was the order of elements, first, define the graph and then, define paper and associate model with graph. Finally, I read the json file, and boom, it works!!

Answer (score 1):

According to joint.js documentation you can use `graph.toJSON()` to save JointJs data as json and then use `graph.fromJSON(JSON.parse(jsonString))` to load it back. Source: https://resources.jointjs.com/docs/jointjs/v3.6/joint.html#dia.Graph.prototype.fromJSON